# Como atribuir um valor zero para uma(s) variável(is) antes de executar o programa?

Tags: android

Primeiramente, ainda sou um pouco leigo no assunto, hehehe

Estou fazendo um programa no Eclipse (Android) que calcula o CR de um estudante, através de dois botões: um se encarrega de somar n notas e seus respectivos pesos (somatório) e armazenar a nota total e o peso total, e outro botão encarregado de fazer a divisão (notatotal/pesototal).

Porém não consigo atribuir valores para notatotal, pesototal e n (iniciais), já que eles devem iniciar com valor = 0, como eu poderia fazer? se atribuir valores iguais a zero para essas variáveis dentro dos botões, o somatório não funciona, visto que a cada clique, o valor voltará a ser zerado e não armazenado e acumulado.

obs.: n é uma variável responsável apenas por determinar quantas notas foram inseridas no cálculo
obs2.: nas fórmulas onde uma variável recebe o valor dela própria mais algo, existe uma mensagem de erro "the local variable X may not have been initialized"

```
package com.example.calculocr_android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CalculoCRActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText editText3;
    EditText editText4;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculo_cr);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                double nota, notatotal, cr;
                int peso, pesototal, n;


                nota = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
                peso = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
                notatotal = notatotal + (nota*peso);
                pesototal = pesototal + peso;
                n = n + 1;
                editText1.setText(String.valueOf(n));
            }

        });


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                double notatotal, cr;
                int pesototal;

                cr = notatotal/pesototal;
                editText4.setText(String.valueOf(cr));

            }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Só uma dica, não utilize button1, button2 etc.. utilize buttonSomarNotas, buttonDividirPesos. não tenha preguiça. é mais saldável e quando precisar de manutenção ficará mais fácil. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sempre pode inicializar os *EditText* com o valor `0` no *activity_calculo_cr.xml* usando o atributo `android:text="0"`

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edittext"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   .....
   .....
   android:text="0"
   android:inputType="number"/>
```

Adicionalmente o atributo `android:inputType="number"` indica que o `EditText` só poderá receber números.

Answer (score 0):

Ao iniciar a variável você também pode colocar int x = 0. Ou fazer como nosso amigo disse ali em cima, setando diretamente no xml.

Answer (score 0):

Yan, em código a única opção é declarar o valor da variável no atributo, da seguinte forma.

```
public class CalculoCRActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText1;
Button button2;
private int variavel = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 .....
```

Dessa forma você garante que a variável irá valer sempre 0 (zero) até você alterar o valor dela.