# Erro ao fazer uma subtração com campos sem valor (Android)

Tags: java, android

Tenho dois  campos do tipo `double`, onde deverá ser feita uma subtração entre os valores. Mas quando eu não insiro algum valor no campo, acontece um erro e a aplicação fecha. Como posso resolver este problema?

Segue o código:

```
final EditText primeiro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.primeiro);
final EditText segundo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segundo);
Button botaoCalcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);

botaoCalcular.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           

        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(primeiro.getText().toString());
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(segundo.getText().toString());     
        double res = num2 - num1;

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
        dialogo.setMessage("Resultado : " + res);
        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
        dialogo.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Em qual linha da o erro?

Comment: Provavelmente o erro ocorre pois está tentando subtrair a variável com valor NULO, se for este o caso deve verificar se é nulo e botar valor 0 no lugar.

Comment: Nao esta acorrendo nenhum erro do jeito que esta porem se eu nao colocar algum valor nos campo na hora que esta executando que acontece o erro e a aplicação e fechada, queria saber como posso resolver isso

Comment: Se não tiver nenhum dado no campo, você estará converterndo null em double. Daí o erro, provavelmente nullpointerException. Valide o campo checando se não é null antes de efetuar a operação.

Comment: Veja nesta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103402/2541) uma forma de evitar que esse erro ocorra sem necessidade de validação.

Comment: Qual erro ocorre, é realmente o `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @ramaral mesmo se os campos vierem com valor default, nada impede de um usuario apagar e tentar fazer a operação vazia, a validação não seria uma forma de se proteger disso?

Comment: Tem razão @DiegoFelipe, o facto de inicializar o campo e puder apenas aceitar números não impede que o usuário o torne nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao desenvolver funcionalidades desta maneira, precisamos nos atentar com a entrada de informação, principalmente garantindo se a ela é valida ou não.

No seu caso, vejo dois grandes pontos que possa causar falha em sua aplicação:

1) - O usuário inserir valores alpha numericos, ou seja, números e letras. Se você tentar fazer algo parecido com:

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble("a");
```

Você irá recever a exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "a"
```

Para evitar isso, você precisa **garantir** que o usuário somente irá inserir valores **válidos** em seu `EditText`. Para isso, você pode colocar o atributo `inputText="number"` diretamente no xml do seu componente. Isso irá fazer com que o estilo do teclado aberto para o usuário inserir as informações seja do tipo `number`, ou seja, impossibilitando o usuário de dar entrada com letras:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/seu_id"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Insira um valor"
   android:inputType="number"/>
```

2) O usuário apertar o botão `calcular` esquecendo de colocar informações válidas, como por exemplo, começou a digitar e apagou todos os valores e o `EditText` ficar vazio. Seria como você tentar fazer isso:

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble("");
```

Você irá receber a exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
```

Para evitar isso, você precisa fazer uma simples **validação de entrada**, para bloquear a operação caso seja inválida:

```
botaoCalcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        String primeiroTexto = primeiro.getText().toString();
        String segundoTexto = segundo.getText().toString();

        if(validaInformacao(primeiroTexto, segundoTexto)){
            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(primeiroTexto);
            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(segundoTexto);     
            double res = num2 - num1;

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");
            dialogo.setMessage("Resultado : " + res);
            dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            dialogo.show();
        }
    }
});

private boolean validaInformacao(String primeiroTexto, String segundoTexto) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(primeiroTexto)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "O primeiro valor é inválido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(segundoTexto)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "O segundo valor é inválido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente :)

Answer (score 1):

Tente validar os campos antes de efetuar qualquer operação:

```
if(primeiro.getText() != null && segundo.getText() != null) {
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(primeiro.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(segundo.getText().toString());

    double res = num2 - num1;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // setando título

    dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");

    // setando mensagem

    dialogo.setMessage("Resultado : " + res);
    // setando botão

    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);

    // chamando o AlertDialog
    dialogo.show();
}
```

Você também pode melhorar o código, exibindo uma mensagem quando tentarem efetuar a operação com campos não preenchidos:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
// setando título
dialogo.setTitle("Resultado");

if(primeiro.getText() != null && segundo.getText() != null){

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(primeiro.getText().toString());  
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(segundo.getText().toString());

    double res = num2 - num1;

    // setando mensagem
    dialogo.setMessage("Resultado : " + res);

    // setando botão
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);

    // chamando o AlertDialog
    dialogo.show();
} else {
    // setando mensagem
    dialogo.setMessage("Os campos não podem ser vazios.");

    // setando botão
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);

    // chamando o AlertDialog
    dialogo.show();
}
```